# In development, hot can I avoid throttling on email reset?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I cannot find how to avoid throttling when trying email reset.
I am doing a lot of manual tests because there are some things involved after a request of a password reset link via email.

I need to be able to stress my environment disabling throttling check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To temporarily disable throttle locally you can comment the throttle line on `App\Http\Kernel.php`, or you can do it for specific routes;

```php
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->withoutMiddleware('throttle:60,1');
```